# Проблема со скриптами node.js на Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ejs

Есть сервер на node.js когда. Я его запускаю локально все работает, как и должно. Но когда я деплою его на Heroku, никаких ошибок не выдает, но просто перестают работать js скрипты. Может уже кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой ?
Вот main.js

```
  'use strict';

    var app = {

      rooms: function(){

    var socket = io('/rooms', { transports: ['websocket'] });

    // When socket connects, get a list of chatrooms
    socket.on('connect', function () {

      // Update rooms list upon emitting updateRoomsList event
      socket.on('updateRoomsList', function(room) {

        // Display an error message upon a user error(i.e. creating a room with an existing title)
        $('.room-create p.message').remove();
        if(room.error != null){
          $('.room-create').append(`<p class="message error">${room.error}</p>`);
        }else{
          app.helpers.updateRoomsList(room);
        }
      });

      // Whenever the user hits the create button, emit createRoom event.
      $('.room-create button').on('click', function(e) {
        var inputEle = $("input[name='title']");
        var roomTitle = inputEle.val().trim();
        if(roomTitle !== '') {
          socket.emit('createRoom', roomTitle);
          inputEle.val('');
        }
      });

    });


    },



    chat: function(roomId, username){

    var socket = io('/chatroom', { transports: ['websocket'] });

      // When socket connects, join the current chatroom
      socket.on('connect', function () {

        socket.emit('join', roomId);

        // Update users list upon emitting updateUsersList event
        socket.on('updateUsersList', function(users, clear) {

          $('.container p.message').remove();
          if(users.error != null){
            $('.container').html(`<p class="message error">${users.error}</p>`);
          }else{
            app.helpers.updateUsersList(users, clear);
          }
        });

        // Whenever the user hits the save button, emit newMessage event.
        $(".chat-message button").on('click', function(e) {

          var textareaEle = $("textarea[name='message']");
          var messageContent = textareaEle.val().trim();
          if(messageContent !== '') {
            var message = { 
              content: messageContent, 
              username: username,
              date: Date.now()
            };

            socket.emit('newMessage', roomId, message);
            textareaEle.val('');
            app.helpers.addMessage(message);
          }
        });

        // Whenever a user leaves the current room, remove the user from users list
        socket.on('removeUser', function(userId) {
          $('li#user-' + userId).remove();
          app.helpers.updateNumOfUsers();
        });

        // Append a new message 
        socket.on('addMessage', function(message) {
          app.helpers.addMessage(message);
        });
      });


    },



     helpers: {

    encodeHTML: function (str){
      return $('<div />').text(str).html();
    },

    // Update rooms list
    updateRoomsList: function(room){
      room.title = this.encodeHTML(room.title);
      room.title = room.title.length > 25? room.title.substr(0, 25) + '...': room.title;
      var html = `<a href="/chat/${room._id}"><li class="room-item">${room.title}</li></a>`;

      if(html === ''){ return; }

      if($(".room-list ul li").length > 0){
        $('.room-list ul').prepend(html);
      }else{
        $('.room-list ul').html('').html(html);
      }

      this.updateNumOfRooms();
    },

    // Update users list
    updateUsersList: function(users, clear){
        if(users.constructor !== Array){
          users = [users];
        }

        var html = '';
        for(var user of users) {
          user.username = this.encodeHTML(user.username);
          html += `<li class="clearfix" id="user-${user._id}">
                     <img src="${user.picture}" alt="${user.username}" />
                     <div class="about">
                        <div class="name">${user.username}</div>
                        <div class="status"><i class="fa fa-circle online"></i> online</div>
                     </div></li>`;
        }

        if(html === ''){ return; }

        if(clear != null && clear == true){
          $('.users-list ul').html('').html(html);
        }else{
          $('.users-list ul').prepend(html);
        }

        this.updateNumOfUsers();
    },

    // Adding a new message to chat history
    addMessage: function(message){
      message.date      = (new Date(message.date)).toLocaleString();
      message.username  = this.encodeHTML(message.username);
      message.content   = this.encodeHTML(message.content);

      var html = `<li>
                    <div class="message-data">
                      <span class="message-data-name">${message.username}</span>
                      <span class="message-data-time">${message.date}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="message my-message" dir="auto">${message.content}</div>
                  </li>`;
      $(html).hide().appendTo('.chat-history ul').slideDown(200);

      // Keep scroll bar down
      $(".chat-history").animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat-history')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    },

    // Update number of rooms
    // This method MUST be called after adding a new room
    updateNumOfRooms: function(){
      var num = $('.room-list ul li').length;
      $('.room-num-rooms').text(num +  " Room(s)");
    },

    // Update number of online users in the current room
    // This method MUST be called after adding, or removing list element(s)
    updateNumOfUsers: function(){
      var num = $('.users-list ul li').length;
      $('.chat-num-users').text(num +  " User(s)");
    }
  }
};
`
```

Ну и как пример Chatroom.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat Morozov</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="chat">
        <div class="chat-header clearfix">
          <img src="<%= user.picture %>" alt="Аватар">
          <div class="chat-about">
            <div class="chat-room"><%= room.title %></div>
            <div class="chat-num-users"> Пользователи</div>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
        </div> <!-- end chat-header -->

        <div class="chat-history">
          <ul>
          </ul>
        </div> <!-- end chat-history -->

        <div class="chat-message clearfix">
          <textarea name="message" placeholder ="Напишите сообшение здесь" rows="3"></textarea> 
          <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
        </div> <!-- end chat-message -->
      </div> <!-- end chat -->

      <div class="controls">
          <a href="/logout" class="logout-btn">Выйти</a>
          <a href="/rooms" class="rooms-btn">Комнаты</a>
      </div>

      <div class="users-list">
        <ul class="list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end container -->
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    <script>$(function(){app.chat('<%= room.id %>', '<%= user.username %>')});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Вот код server.js

```
'use strict';

// Chat application dependencies
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var path        = require('path');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var flash       = require('connect-flash');

// Chat application components
var routes      = require('./app/routes');
var session     = require('./app/session');
var passport    = require('./app/auth');
var ioServer    = require('./app/socket')(app);
var logger      = require('./app/logger');

// Set the port number
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(session);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use('/', routes);

// Middleware to catch 404 errors
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).sendFile(process.cwd() + '/app/views/404.htm');
});

ioServer.listen(port);
```

Comment: где находится сервер? и какой его код? как минимум нужно добавить логи на сервер и посмотреть что в них.

Comment: В логах пусто .-. Сервер работает через Heroku у них там свой репозиторий. Описание основого файла дополнил

Comment: что значит _просто перестают работать js скрипты_? Не отправляются запросы на сервер? Не получается ответ от сервера? Получается не тот ответ который ожидался? Доходит ли запрос до сервера? Что происходит с ним на сервере?

Comment: Запросы на получение страницы проходят. Связь с БД есть. Но не печатаются сообщения, не выводиться список пользователей. Не создаются новые комнаты. Все это описано в main.js. В логах ошибки нет, на localhost все работает. Не работает это именно на Heroku

Comment: выполнялась ли команда: `heroku features:enable http-session-affinity`? [Apps using Socket.io should enable session affinity.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets)

Comment: нет. Выполнил, проверил все по статье не помогло .-. так же на localhost работает на heroku нет. Чисто не выполняется main.js

Comment: Что значит _не выполняется main.js_? Не выполняться он может только в случае если он не загрузился. В противном случае он выполняется и нужно только определить в каком месте ошибка.   Добавь логов, чтобы определить до какого места доходит. Посмотри во вкладке network - работает ли websocket, открывается ли соединение и что там передается

Comment: Нашел, выдает вот это Mixed Content: The page at 'https://****-for***ss-6***6.herokuapp.com/chat/5c5f0a96382f160cf02f9c30' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.  И вот это ссылка заблочена https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: ну вот :-) со страницы https нельзя делать запросы на http, а наоборот можно, поэтому ссылки на cdn замени либо на https либо чтобы они начинались просто с `//`

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена :3